# Get default (on screen) PGraphics context in Processing

Tags: java, graphics, processing, intersection

Is it possible to get the graphics context which is rendered on screen in Processing?

I have a function which I would like to use to draw the same shapes to both the screen and a back buffer for intersection testing. If I could call it twice with different PGraphics contexts as arguments that would remove a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: example code required to see what you're actually doing, to see whether your question is what you really want, or whether it's an XY question. Without further information, just pass your function "this" while in global context to pass in the PApplet.

Comment: I think I know exactly what the OP is asking (I'm having this problem too). Look at [this paste](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aqThWx8N).

Answer (score 4):

To get the `PGraphics` object associated with a `PApplet`
can be found in the `g` property, as stated in [the docs](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#g).

So, as the applet is stored in `this`, you'd do **`this.g` or simply `g`** to get it.

In other words:

```
noStroke();
g.noStroke();
this.noStroke();
this.g.noStroke();
```

The four statements above **are all equivalent**.

**Note:** this doesn't work on ProcessingJS, I hope it's fixed soon, see [the bug](https://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284/tickets/1916-g-variable-feature-of-processingorg-not-available-in-processingjs).